# Nested for loop in three spatial dimensions - OMP

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested, spatial

I'm developing in C/C++, gcc 4.8.4, no C++11 atm. I'm using OMP pragmata. Often we are iterating over a 3D-array:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(size_t i = startI ; i < stopI ; i++) {
 for(size_t j = startJ ; j < stopJ ; j++) {
  for(size_t k = startK ; k < stopK ; k++) {
   //example calculations
   valueIJK = func1(i,j,k);
   newArray[i][j][k] = func2(oldArray[i][j][k]) * valueIJK;       
  }
 }
}
```

My first thought is:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(size_t i[0] = start[0] ; i[0] < stop[0] ; i[0]++) {
 for(size_t i[1] = start[1] ; i[1] < stop[1] ; i[1]++) {
  for(size_t i[2] = start[2] ; i[2] < stop[2] ; i[2]++) {
   //example calculations
   //valueIJK = func1(i,j,k);
   //newArray[i][j][k] = func2(oldArray[i][j][k]) * valueIJK;       
  }
 }
}
```

But I think, the best would be something like:

```
double i[3];
double start[3];
double stop[3];
/* set start, stop values */
/* next line is highly incorrect code */
#pragma omp parallel for
vectorized_for(i = start ; i < stop ; i++)
   //example calculations
   //valueIJK = func1(i,j,k);
   //newArray[i][j][k] = func2(oldArray[i][j][k]) * valueIJK;       
}
```

My questions now:

1. Are you understanding what I want :D I can explain more
2. Can this be implemented? Hiding the three nested for loops ? Something like "for each combination of (i,j,k) do the following stuff" ? Like the for_each in  ?
3. Will it still be recognized by omp?
4. Is it as fast as before?

Thank you very much for your thoughts :)

Comment: For each combination of (i,j,k) - one way to do it is to convert (i,j,k)   to index, index = k + j * max_k + i * max_k * max_i. Then use 1D array [index] = value.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the comment, we are already doing this in some other parts of the code. However, i need the triple (i,j,k). If i use something like `for(index=0;index<max_i*max_j*max_k;index++)` then I don't have i,j,k available for e.g. `func1`.

Comment: Well, you can always go back from index to (i,j,k):  i = index / (max_k*max_i), j = (index - i * max_k*max_i) / map_k, k = index -  i * max_k*max_i - j * map_k, can be done faster of course.... :D, if you have performance issues you can also read about OcTree